# I have a button that redirects the another form I want that button value in the dropdown as a selected option in the next page form?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Here is a code button code

```
    <h2 class="single-heading">
        <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
            Review
        <a href="
            <?php echo home_url().'/submit-review/'; ?>
        " class="btn btn-light text-right pbd-title-btn" id="title" value="
            <?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?>
        " >
        <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true">
        </i>Write a Review</a>
    </h2>
```

I want that post or button value in the dropdown list as a selected value. here is a second page form code

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
    <label class="control-label">Select Breeder Name/Entity <span class="required">*</span></label>
        <select class="category form-control" data-placeholder="Select an option" id="pbd_review_name" name="pbd_review_name_id" >
            <option value="">Select an option</option>
                <?php $res = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'review', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
                    if(!empty($res)){
                        foreach($res as $row){
                            $b_name = $row->post_title;
                            $b_photo = get_post_meta($row->ID,'photo',true);
                            $b_suburb = get_post_meta($row->ID,'suburb',true);
                            $b_state = get_post_meta($row->ID,'state',true);
                            $b_website = get_post_meta($row->ID,'website',true);
                            echo '<option value="'.$row->ID.'" data-name="'.$b_name.'" data-photo="'.$b_photo.'" data-suburb="'.$b_suburb.'" data-state="'.$b_state.'" data-website="'.$b_website.'" >'.$b_name.'</option>';
                        }
                    }
                ?>
        </select>
</div>
```

In this dropdown list posts value is already prompted. But i want post name as a selected option value.

I hope you understand my question.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use method $_GET for trasport value to other page then use selected method:

```
            <?php 
            $value=$_GET['VALUE1']
            $othervalue=$_GET['VALUE2']
            echo '<option value="$value" selected>$othervalue</option>
```

EDIT:
All code, in the first page a use "/submit-review.php?valueid=$ID&valuename=$NAME" for trasport value to next page :

```
<h2 class="single-heading">
    <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
        Review
    <a href="
        <?php echo home_url().'/submit-review.php?valueid=$ID&valuename=$NAME'; ?>
    " class="btn btn-light text-right pbd-title-btn" id="title" value="
        <?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?>
    " >
    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true">
    </i>Write a Review</a>
</h2>
```

And on the next page i will convert $_GET to the local variable for use it on selected box:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
<label class="control-label">Select Breeder Name/Entity <span class="required">*</span></label>
    <select class="category form-control" data-placeholder="Select an option" id="pbd_review_name" name="pbd_review_name_id" >

            <?php 
            $valueID= $_GET['valueid'];
            $valueNAME= $_GET['valuename'];
            echo "<option value='$valueID' selected>$valueNAME</option>"; 
            $res = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'review', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
                if(!empty($res)){
                    foreach($res as $row){
                        $b_name = $row->post_title;
                        $b_photo = get_post_meta($row->ID,'photo',true);
                        $b_suburb = get_post_meta($row->ID,'suburb',true);
                        $b_state = get_post_meta($row->ID,'state',true);
                        $b_website = get_post_meta($row->ID,'website',true);
                        echo '<option value="'.$row->ID.'" data-name="'.$b_name.'" data-photo="'.$b_photo.'" data-suburb="'.$b_suburb.'" data-state="'.$b_state.'" data-website="'.$b_website.'" >'.$b_name.'</option>';
                    }
                }
            ?>
    </select>
```

---

edit 3:

use SESSION for resolve your problem(first page):

```
  <h2 class="single-heading">
    <?php echo get_the_title(); ?>
        Review
    <a href="
        <?php echo home_url().'/submit-review/'; ?>
    " class="btn btn-light text-right pbd-title-btn" id="title" value="
        <?php echo get_the_title($post->ID); ?>
    " >
    <i class="fa fa-plus" aria-hidden="true">
    </i>Write a Review</a>
</h2>
$_SESSION['id'] = $post->ID;
$_SESSION['title'] = $post->title;
```

On the second page:

```
<div class="col-md-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12 col-sm-12">
<label class="control-label">Select Breeder Name/Entity <span class="required">*</span></label>
<select class="category form-control" data-placeholder="Select an option" id="pbd_review_name" name="pbd_review_name_id" >

        <?php 
        $valueID= $_SESSION['id'];
        $valueNAME= $_SESSION['title'];
        echo "<option value='$valueID' selected>$valueNAME</option>"; 
        $res = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'review', 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
            if(!empty($res)){
                foreach($res as $row){
                    $b_name = $row->post_title;
                    $b_photo = get_post_meta($row->ID,'photo',true);
                    $b_suburb = get_post_meta($row->ID,'suburb',true);
                    $b_state = get_post_meta($row->ID,'state',true);
                    $b_website = get_post_meta($row->ID,'website',true);
                    echo '<option value="'.$row->ID.'" data-name="'.$b_name.'" data-photo="'.$b_photo.'" data-suburb="'.$b_suburb.'" data-state="'.$b_state.'" data-website="'.$b_website.'" >'.$b_name.'</option>';
                }
            }
        ?>
</select>
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203241/discussion-on-answer-by-simone-rossaini-i-have-a-button-that-redirects-the-anoth).

Answer (score 0):

You can try sending the value in $_REQUEST/$_POST and the compare the value in the dropdown:

```
<?php 
    $value=$_REQUEST['value']; //value with which you want to compare
    //then in loop 
    echo '<option value="'.$row->ID.'" <?php echo ($val == $value)?"selected":"" ?> >'.$b_name.'</option>';  

//$val is the value which is received in dropdown i.e $row->ID $value is the value you received in $_REQUEST
```